# Simple HTTP server in Python. How to GET files from DIR_PATH?

Tags: python-3.x, httpserver, simplehttpserver

I have such code for running simple server on Python 3. I know that I can just use something like this `python -m http.server 8080`, however I want to understand how it works and set limits for serving files extensions.

I try to use `path.join(DIR_PATH, self.path)`, but seems that doesn't work.

```
>> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]: 'c:/test.html'
```

But `DIR_PATH = 'C:\script_path\src\'`
However it works for `/` requested path and server opens `index.html`.

Therefore, `path.join(DIR_PATH, 'index.html')` is works.

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from os import path

DIR_PATH = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))

hostName = "localhost"
hostPort = 8080


class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    content_type = 'text/html'

    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', self.content_type)
        self.send_header('Content-Length', path.getsize(self.getPath()))
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write(self.getContent(self.getPath()))

    def getPath(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            content_path = path.join(DIR_PATH, 'index.html')
        else:
            content_path = path.join(DIR_PATH, self.path)
        return content_path

    def getContent(self, content_path):
        with open(content_path, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            content = f.read()
        return bytes(content, 'utf-8')

myServer = HTTPServer((hostName, hostPort), RequestHandler)
myServer.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found issue.

It doesn't work becuse:

`self.path` has `/` symbol in a string and `path.join` can't find file in Windows.

Here is fixed row:

`content_path = path.join(DIR_PATH, str(self.path)[1:])`

`str(self.path)[1:]` removes first symbol (`/`) from a `self.path` string.